# Avoid dhclient-script overide ntp on amazon linux ami

Tags: linux, dhcp, time, ntp

We're using emr cluster on amazon webservices 'aws'. We are using default 'Amazon Linux AMI' images without customization. It looks to me that the dhclient-script is fetching configurations from our companies dhcp (dynamic host configuration protocol), especially ntp (network time protocol)

As an example on the master node, the dhclient-script appends our companies ntp servers to the `/etc/ntp.conf` file.

```
[hadoop@ip-10-5-21-157 ~]$ grep ^server /etc/ntp.conf 
server 0.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 10.2.78.21   # added by /sbin/dhclient-script
server 10.2.78.22   # added by /sbin/dhclient-script
server 10.2.78.23   # added by /sbin/dhclient-script
server 10.2.78.24   # added by /sbin/dhclient-script
```

The ip addresses 10.2.78.21-24 resolve to `clockNN.ntp.mycompany.com`

How can this be avoided so that we just use the default settings from amazon?

**EDIT** We had issues while runnig a pig aggregation on an emr cluster. An example exception stacktrace is:

```
18/01/07 13:50:23 INFO tez.TezJob: DAG Status: status=FAILED, progress=TotalTasks: 4737 Succeeded: 3777 Running: 0 Failed: 1 Killed: 959 FailedTaskAttempts: 428 KilledTaskAttempts: 309, diagnostics=Vertex failed, vertexName=scope-421, vertexId=vertex_1515326570070_0001_1_04, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1515326570070_0001_1_04_002846, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Container launch failed for container_1515326570070_0001_01_000599 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
This token is expired. current time is 1515332813920 found 1515330236564
Note: System times on machines may be out of sync. Check system time and time zones.
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor51.newInstance(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
       at org.apache.tez.dag.app.launcher.TezContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(TezContainerLauncherImpl.java:160)
       at org.apache.tez.dag.app.launcher.TezContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(TezContainerLauncherImpl.java:353)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

A root cause for (some of) the emr machines (vm's, images, nodes?) system time to be off could have been our companies DNS servers. (But that's a wild guess.) One idea to remove this possibility is to remove those ntp servers from /etc/ntp.conf file and re-initialize the system times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, i came up with the following:

Created file `modify_ntp_config.sh` on S3:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eEu

ntp_config_file="${1:-example_config}"
echo "Removing 'server 10.*' entries from \"$ntp_config_file\""
sudo sed -i -e '/server 10.*/d' $ntp_config_file
echo "Reinitialize ntp"
sudo service ntpd stop
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
sudo service ntpd start
```

Copied this file to s3:

```
$ aws s3 cp /var/tmp/modify_ntp_config.sh \
    s3://<s3-bucket-name>/data/scripts/modify_ntp_config.sh
```

And then using `aws-tools`:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "..." [...cluster create options ...] \
    --steps \
Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name=CustomJAR,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,\
Jar=s3://<region>.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,\
Args=["s3://<s3-bucket-name>/data/scripts/modify_ntp_config.sh","/etc/ntp.conf"]
```

Results in the following log output (copied from s3 to localdisk)

```
$ aws s3 cp --recursive s3://<s3-bucket-name>/log/<cluster-id>/steps/<step-id>/ /var/tmp/5HKO7
download: s3://[...]/stdout.gz to ../../var/tmp/5HKO7/stdout.gz
download: s3://[...]/stderr.gz to ../../var/tmp/5HKO7/stderr.gz
download: s3://[...]/controller.gz to ../../var/tmp/5HKO7/controller.gz

$ zcat /var/tmp/5HKO7/stdout.gz 
Downloading 's3://<s3-bucket-name>/data/scripts/modify_ntp_config.sh' to '/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/[...]/.'
Removing 'server 10.*' entries from "/etc/ntp.conf"
Reinitialize ntp
Shutting down ntpd: [  OK  ]
Starting ntpd: [  OK  ]

$ zcat /var/tmp/5HKO7/stderr.gz 
Command exiting with ret '0'
```

**NOTE:** Another way would be to use it on already running emr cluster using `aws emr add-steps`.

```
$ aws emr add-steps --cluster-id "j-<emr_cluster_id>"\
--steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name=CustomJAR,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,\
Jar=s3://<region>.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,\
Args=["s3://<s3-bucket-name>/data/scripts/modify_ntp_config.sh","/etc/ntp.conf"]
```

References:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/DeveloperGuide//emr-hadoop-script.html
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/add-steps.html
  https://askubuntu.com/questions/254826/how-to-force-a-clock-update-using-ntp
  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158802/how-to-update-ntp-without-shutting-down-the-ntp-daemon